# Angular 2 import not being loaded when declarations definition present

Tags: angular, typescript, gulp

I am trying to start using angular 2 components within my angular 1 app using the upgrade adapter. I have followed the instructions here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html, but when I add the component to declarations in the AppModule it gives me this error:

```
(index):47 Error: (SystemJS) Cannot read property 'downgradeNg2Component' of undefined(…)
(anonymous function) @ (index):47ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:203
Zone.run @ zone.js:96(anonymous function) @ zone.js:462
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:236Zone.runTask @ zone.js:136
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:368ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:308
nrWrapper @ (index):37
```

I haven't been able to find anyone having a similar issue and everything works okay until I add the component to the declarations in the AppModule decorator.

Here is my app.component.ts file:

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { adapter } from '../adapter';

console.log('COMPONENT');
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
  `
})
export class HelloComponent {
}

angular.module('nova.directives', [])
  .directive('hello', [adapter.downgradeNg2Component(HelloComponent)])
```

Here is the main.ts file:

```
import { AppModule } from './ng2app.module';
import { adapter } from './adapter';
console.log('MAIN');

adapter.bootstrap(document.querySelector('html'), ['nova']);
```

adapter.ts:

```
import { AppModule } from './ng2app.module';

console.log('ADAPTER');
export const adapter = new UpgradeAdapter(AppModule);
```

ng2app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HelloComponent } from './ng2Components/app.component';

console.log('MODULE');

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ HelloComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

It seems like app.component.ts is being loaded before everything else for some reason.

Here is my systemjs.config file (from the quickstart):

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    baseUrl: 'app',
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',
      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      '@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',
      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api',
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': {
        main: './index.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

The app uses gulp to transpile the typescript files.

Any help tracking down what is going on would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not entirely sure why the imports were breaking previously, but I was able to get it working by moving the call to downgradeNg2Component into the ng2app.module.ts file and just exporting the adapter from there as well. I will just have to add all of my directive declarations in that file to bind them to the angular 1 app.